# How to add a page heading in front of your page numbers in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm looking to add a page heading in front of the page numbers in GridView. I have highlighted what I am trying to achieve with the picture below with the arrow.

[image]

Comment: Try with the GridView's PagerTemplate. If you have tried something and can't get it running, update your question with your code and specify where the problem is. You'll get more help then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sami mentioned in the comments above, GridView's PagerTemplate should allow you to do this easily. Here's a tutorial on how to implement a PagerTemplate:

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/gvpagertemplate-csharp/

Please note that in the tutorial they're also showing how to add a dropdown to select the page. This is more complicated that what you're trying to do, but, if you notice, they're also modifying the text in front of the page listing. Look for code similar to the following:

```
<asp:label id="labelPagerMessage" text="Page:" runat="server"/>
```